# What is Virtual Serial Port in QEMU?

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, qemu, serial-port, pty

Ubuntu 20.04 both on host and guest.

I'm new to QEMU and trying to set up guest-host communication via serial port. The [QEMU documentation](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/invocation.html#hxtool-9) says that `-serial dev` option:

```
Redirect the virtual serial port to host character device dev.
```

So I ran QEMU VM with the option `-serial pty` and got the following console output:

```
char device redirected to /dev/pts/9 (label serial0)
```

***QUESTION:*** On host I have the specified device `/dev/pts/9` and writing to it with

```
echo hello > /dev/pts/9
```

where should I read the output on the guest from?

Answer (score 4):

When you expose a device with `-serial`, that will show up as a serial port in your virtual machine. If you look at the kernel log, you should see something like:

```
Dec 25 15:38:31 fedora kernel: 00:04: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

So if inside the virtual machine I run:

```
echo hello > /dev/ttyS0
```

Then on the host I will see:

```
$ cat /dev/pts/4
hello
```